# Getting errors when trying to draw complex polygons with triangles in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to draw complex 2d polygons in OpenGL. I wrote all my rendering methods with GL_TRIANGLES so I'm not trying to change to GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or anything like that.

Essentially, I have a list of ordered coordinates and I want to create a polygon from them like this:
[image]

The method I was originally using was to create a triangle between the first vertex and the next two and do that until the triangle is betweeen the first and last two vertices. However, on an L shaped polygon as the one above, I get something like this:

[image]

As you can see, indexing the vertices this way draws triangles in areas where there should be no triangles. How can I index the vertices with GL_TRIANGLES to get something like the first result? The vertices will be different every single time but are always in clockwise order so I need a generalized approach for any polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the problem in two stages consisting of turning the polygon into convex sub-polygons, and then triangulate each of the sub-polygons. The algorithm to triangulate a sub polygon (`triangulatePoly`) is a fairly simple recursive function that takes in a polygon and checks if it has 3 points. If it does, it returns, if not, it creates a triangle from the first 3 points adds it to a list and decrements the polygon by that triangle, leaving you with a list of triangles that comprise the polygon.

The convex sub-polygon algorithm (`decomposePoly`) is harder to explain as it is quite complicated and so if you want to understand it, it is [here](https://mpen.ca/406/bayazit).

Finally, here is an implementation, written with OpenGL2 and quite clustered for brevity.

```
// ######################

public class Point {
public float x;
public float y;

public Point(float _x, float _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
}

public static float area(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    return (((b.x - a.x)*(c.y - a.y))-((c.x - a.x)*(b.y - a.y)));
}

public static boolean left(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    return area(a, b, c) > 0;
}

public static boolean leftOn(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    return area(a, b, c) >= 0;
}

public static boolean rightOn(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    return area(a, b, c) <= 0;
}


public static boolean right(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    return area(a, b, c) < 0;
}

public static float sqdist(Point a, Point b) {
    float dx = b.x - a.x;
    float dy = b.y - a.y;
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}
} 

// ######################

import java.util.Vector;
public class Polygon extends Vector<Point> {
        @Override
        public Point get(int i)  {
            // hacky way of getting the modulo
            return super.get(((i % this.size()) + this.size()) % this.size());
        }
}

// ######################

import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class DecomposePolyExample {

    private long window;

    private int WIDTH = 300;
    private int HEIGHT = 300;

    private float mouse_x = WIDTH / 2;
    private float mouse_y = HEIGHT / 2;

    private Polygon incPoly = new Polygon();

    private Vector<Polygon> polys = new Vector<Polygon>();
    private Vector<Polygon> tris = new Vector<Polygon>();
    private Vector<Point> steinerPoints = new Vector<Point>();
    private Vector<Point> reflexVertices = new Vector<Point>();

    private boolean polyComplete = false;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL" + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void init() {

        // Setup and error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
            }
        });

        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, (window, x, y) -> {
            mouse_x = (float)x;
            mouse_y = HEIGHT - (float)y;
        });

        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, (window, button, action, mods) -> {
            if (action != GLFW_PRESS){
                return;
            }
            int lClick = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT);
            if (lClick == GLFW_PRESS)
            {
                Point p = new Point(mouse_x, mouse_y);
                incPoly.add(p);
            }
            int rClick = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT);
            if (rClick == GLFW_PRESS)
            {
                polyComplete = true;
                incPoly = makeCCW(incPoly);
                decomposePoly(incPoly);
                triangulatePoly(polys); 
            }
        });

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    public Point toNDC(Point p) {
        float x = 2*p.x / WIDTH - 1;
        float y = 2*p.y / HEIGHT - 1;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Polygon makeCCW(Polygon poly) {
        int br = 0;

        // find bottom right point
        for (int i = 1; i < poly.size(); ++i) {
            if (poly.get(i).y < poly.get(br).y || (poly.get(i).y == poly.get(br).y && poly.get(i).x > poly.get(br).x)) {
                br = i;
            }
        }

        // reverse poly if clockwise
        if (!Point.left(poly.get(br - 1), poly.get(br), poly.get(br + 1))) {
            Collections.reverse(poly);
        }
       return poly;
    }

    public boolean isReflex(Polygon poly, int i) {  
        return Point.right(poly.get(i - 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(i + 1));
    }

    public boolean eq(float a, float b) {
        return Math.abs(a - b) <= 1e-8;
    }

    Point intersection(Point p1, Point p2, Point q1, Point q2) {
        Point i = new Point(0,0);
        float a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, det;
        a1 = p2.y - p1.y;
        b1 = p1.x - p2.x;
        c1 = a1 * p1.x + b1 * p1.y;
        a2 = q2.y - q1.y;
        b2 = q1.x - q2.x;
        c2 = a2 * q1.x + b2 * q1.y;
        det = a1 * b2 - a2*b1;
        if (!eq(det, 0)) { // lines are not parallel
            i.x = (b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / det;
            i.y = (a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / det;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void decomposePoly(Polygon poly) {
        Point upperInt = new Point(0,0);
        Point lowerInt = new Point(0,0);
        Point p = new Point(0,0);
        Point closestVert = new Point(0,0);

        float upperDist, lowerDist, d, closestDist;
        int upperIndex = 0;
        int lowerIndex = 0;
        int closestIndex = 0;
        Polygon lowerPoly = new Polygon();
        Polygon upperPoly = new Polygon();
        for (int i = 0; i < poly.size(); ++i) {
            if (isReflex(poly, i)) {
                reflexVertices.add(poly.get(i));
                upperDist = lowerDist = Float.MAX_VALUE;
                for (int j = 0; j < poly.size(); ++j) {
                    if (Point.left(poly.get(i - 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j))
                            && Point.rightOn(poly.get(i - 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j - 1))) { // if line intersects with an edge
                        p = intersection(poly.get(i - 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j), poly.get(j - 1)); // find the point of intersection
                        if (Point.right(poly.get(i + 1), poly.get(i), p)) { // make sure it's inside the poly
                            d = Point.sqdist(poly.get(i), p);
                            if (d < lowerDist) { // keep only the closest intersection
                                lowerDist = d;
                                lowerInt = p;
                                lowerIndex = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (Point.left(poly.get(i + 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j + 1))
                            && Point.rightOn(poly.get(i + 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j))) {
                        p = intersection(poly.get(i + 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j), poly.get(j + 1));
                        if (Point.left(poly.get(i - 1), poly.get(i), p)) {
                            d = Point.sqdist(poly.get(i), p);
                            if (d < upperDist) {
                                upperDist = d;
                                upperInt = p;
                                upperIndex = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // if there are no vertices to connect to, choose a point in the middle
                if (lowerIndex == (upperIndex + 1) % poly.size()) {
                    p.x = (lowerInt.x + upperInt.x) / 2;
                    p.y = (lowerInt.y + upperInt.y) / 2;
                    steinerPoints.add(p);

                    if (i < upperIndex) {
                        for (int j = i; j < upperIndex + 1; j++) {
                            lowerPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }
                        lowerPoly.add(p);
                        upperPoly.add(p);
                        if (lowerIndex != 0) {
                            for (int j = lowerIndex; j < poly.size(); j++) {
                                upperPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                            upperPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (i != 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                                lowerPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < upperIndex + 1; j++) {
                            lowerPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }
                        lowerPoly.add(p);
                        upperPoly.add(p);
                        for (int j = lowerIndex; j < i + 1; j++) {
                            upperPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // connect to the closest point within the triangle

                    if (lowerIndex > upperIndex) {
                        upperIndex += poly.size();
                    }
                    closestDist = Float.MAX_VALUE;
                    for (int j = lowerIndex; j <= upperIndex; ++j) {
                        if (Point.leftOn(poly.get(i - 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j))
                                && Point.rightOn(poly.get(i + 1), poly.get(i), poly.get(j))) {
                            d = Point.sqdist(poly.get(i), poly.get(j));
                            if (d < closestDist) {
                                closestDist = d;
                                closestVert = poly.get(j);
                                closestIndex = j % poly.size();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < closestIndex) {
                        for (int j = i; j < closestIndex + 1; j++) {
                            lowerPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }

                        if (closestIndex != 0) {
                            for (int j = closestIndex; j < poly.size(); j++) {
                                upperPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                            upperPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (i != 0) {
                            for (int j = i; j < poly.size(); j++) {
                                lowerPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < closestIndex + 1; j++) {
                            lowerPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }
                        for (int j = closestIndex; j < i + 1; j++) {
                            upperPoly.add(poly.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                }
                // solve smallest poly first
                if (lowerPoly.size() < upperPoly.size()) {
                    decomposePoly(lowerPoly);
                    decomposePoly(upperPoly);
                } else {
                    decomposePoly(upperPoly);
                    decomposePoly(lowerPoly);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        polys.add(poly);
    }


    public void triangulatePoly(Vector<Polygon> polys) {
        for (int i = 0; i < polys.size(); i++) {
            Polygon poly = polys.get(i);
            // return if poly is a triangle
            if (poly.size() == 3) {
                tris.add(poly);
                polys.remove(i);
            }
            else {
                // split poly into new triangle and poly
                Polygon tri = new Polygon();
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    tri.add(poly.get(j));
                }
                Polygon newPoly = new Polygon();
                newPoly.add(poly.get(0));
                for (int k = 2; k < poly.size(); k++) {
                    newPoly.add(poly.get(k));
                }
                polys.set(i, newPoly);
                tris.add(tri);
            }
        }
        if (polys.size() != 0) {
            triangulatePoly(polys);
        }
    }

    private void loop() {
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer
            System.out.println(tris.size());
            if (!polyComplete) {
                GL11.glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
                for (int i = 0; i < incPoly.size(); ++i) {
                    Point p_ndc = toNDC(incPoly.get(i));
                    GL11.glVertex2f(p_ndc.x, p_ndc.y);
                }
                GL11.glEnd();
            } else {
                // polygon outlines (thin)
                for (int i = 0; i < tris.size(); ++i) {
                    GL11.glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
                    for (int j = 0; j < tris.get(i).size(); ++j) {
                        Point p_ndc = toNDC(tris.get(i).get(j));
                        GL11.glVertex2f(p_ndc.x, p_ndc.y);
                    }
                    GL11.glEnd();
                }

                GL11.glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
                for (int i = 0; i < incPoly.size(); ++i) {
                    Point p_ndc = toNDC(incPoly.get(i));
                    GL11.glVertex2f(p_ndc.x, p_ndc.y);
                }
                GL11.glEnd();
            }

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DecomposePolyExample().run();
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image: demo]

Comment: Obviously, but for any polygon how can you determine that you need to start with point 0? If the index buffer started with 1, the issue remains.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking about the specific order of the vertices? Because it doesn't make a difference; 0 2 1 is the same as 2 1 0. Please post your index buffer.

Comment: I'm trying to automatically generate these vertices for any polygon. How can you automatically generate these indices and ensure that OpenGL doesn't draw outside the polygon as shown in the original question? I can manually create index buffers that work but the question is how to do it automatically.

Comment: OH! My apologies. So, you can use an algorithm to break the polygon into convex polygons.  There should be another algorithm to properly triangulate each submesh.

Answer (score 1):

[Decompose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) your polygon into triangles or use the [stencil buffer method](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13).

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL only convex polygons can be drawn correctly. As mentioned in an an other answer you can use the [Stencil Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Stencil_Test) buffet to draw a concave polygons. The algorithm is described in detail at
[Drawing Filled, Concave Polygons Using the Stencil Buffer](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13)
or [Drawing Filled, Concave Polygons Using the Stencil Buffer (OpenGL Programming)](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/drawing-filled-concave-polygons-using-the-stencil-buffer-opengl-programming/).

Fraw the polygon by the [Triangle primitiv](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) type `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. e.g:

```
1       2
 +-----+
 |     |
 |     |3     4
 |     +-----+
 |           |
 |           |
 +-----------+
0             5
```

Draw the `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` *1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 0*
Of course it is possible to start with any point e.g. *3 - 4 - 5 - 0 - 1 - 2*

The polygon has to be draw twice. The first time the stencil buffer is set, but nothing is drawn in the color buffer at all. The stencil buffer is inverted, every time when a fragment is drawn. If a pixel is covered an even number of times, the value in the stencil buffers is zero; otherwise, it's 1.
At the end the polygon is drawn a 2nd time. This time the color buffer is drawn. The stencil test is enabled and ensures that only the fragments are drawn where the stencil buffer is 1:

```java
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
GL11.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
GL11.glStencilOp(GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_INVERT);
GL11.glStencilFunc(GL11.GL_ALWAYS, 0x1, 0x1);

// draw the polygon the 1st time: set the stencil buffer
// GL_TRIANGLE_FAN: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 0

GL11.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
GL11.glStencilOp(GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP);
GL11.glStencilFunc(GL11.GL_EQUAL, 0x1, 0x1);

// draw the polygon the 2nd time: draw to color buffer by using the stencil test
// GL_TRIANGLE_FAN: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 0

GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```